# Using a button instead of checkbox for ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, ng-class

I am using successfully this ng-class code.

html

```
  <div class="col-sm-5" ng-class="{myDynamicWidth: MYWIDTH}"   ng-repeat="x in names">

  ...

  </div>

 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="MYWIDTH">WIDE
```

css

```
.myDynamicWidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

How do I achieve the same result with a button instead of a checkbox???

One click enlarge, another click on the same button minimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can toggle the value of `MYWIDTH` by doing this

```
<button ng-click="MYWIDTH = !MYWIDTH">Wide</button>
```

Comment: I am going to, still have to wait 7 minutes :D